# Oracle 10g - optimize WHERE IS NOT NULL

Tags: oracle, optimization, null

We have Oracle 10g and we need to query a table (no `JOIN`s) and filter out rows where 1 of the columns is null. When we do this - `WHERE OurColumn IS NOT NULL` - we get a full table scan on a very large table - BAD BAD BAD. The column has an index on it, but it gets ignored in this instance. Are there any solutions to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The optimizer thinks that the full table scan will be better.

If there are just a few `NULL` rows, the optimizer is right.

If you are absolutely sure that the index access will be faster (that is, you have more than `75%` rows with `col1 IS NULL`), then hint your query:

```
SELECT  /*+ INDEX (t index_name_on_col1) */
        *
FROM    mytable t
WHERE   col1 IS NOT NULL
```

Why `75%`?

Because using `INDEX SCAN` to retrieve values not covered by the index implies a hidden join on `ROWID`, which costs about `4` times as much as table scan.

If the index range includes more than `25%` of rows, the table scan is usually faster.

As mentioned by `Tony Andrews`, clustering factor is more accurate method to measure this value, but `25%` is still a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Quassnoi, where are you getting that 75%? If there are a million rows and only one is null, why would using an index on that columns be slower than a table scan?

Comment: Because index impies a hidden join on ROWID, which costs about 4 times as much as table scan. Is the index selectivity is lower than 25%, the table scan is usually faster.

Comment: In a full table scan, you simply iterate over all the rows in the table; if you do a index scan, you first have to read the index, and after that read the table. From a certain point the cost of reading an index is higher than simply reading the whole table.

Comment: You need to be careful about the index type here - if it's a standard B-Tree index on a single column then "is null" or "is not null" clauses will never use an index.

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` on a nullable column makes an index on this column eligible for including in a plan, Oracle is smart enough for this :)

Comment: @Quassnoi, your explanation is great.  I took the liberty to add your comment to the main text.

Answer (score 17):

The optimiser will make its decision based on the relative cost of the full table scan and  using the index.  This mainly comes down to how many blocks will have to be read to satisfy the query.  The 25%/75% rule of thumb mentioned in another answer is simplistic: in some cases a full table scan will make sense even to get 1% of the rows - i.e. if those rows happen to be spread around many blocks.

For example, consider this table:

```
SQL> create table t1 as select object_id, object_name from all_objects;

Table created.
SQL> alter table t1 modify object_id null;

Table altered.

SQL> update t1 set object_id = null
  2  where mod(object_id,100) != 0
  3  /

84558 rows updated.

SQL> analyze table t1 compute statistics;

Table analyzed.

SQL> select count(*) from t1 where object_id is not null;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       861
```

As you can see, only approximately 1% of the rows in T1 have a non-null object_id.  But due to the way I built the table, these 861 rows will be spread more or less evenly around the table.  Therefore, the query:

```
select * from t1 where object_id is not null;
```

is likely to visit almost every block in T1 to get data, even if the optimiser used the index.  It makes sense then to dispense with the index and go for a full table scan!

A key statistic to help identify this situation is the index clustering factor:

```
SQL> select clustering_factor from user_indexes where index_name='T1_IDX';

CLUSTERING_FACTOR
-----------------
              460
```

This value 460 is quite high (compared to the 861 rows in the index), and suggests that a full table scan will be used.  See [this DBAZine article on clustering factors](http://web.archive.org/web/20090604211355/http://www.dbazine.com/oracle/or-articles/hotka2).

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing a select *, then it would make sense to do a table scan rather than using the index. If you know which columns you are interested in, you could create a covered index with those colums plus the one you are applying the IS NOT NULL condition.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the type of index you have on the table.

Most B-tree indexes do **not** store null entries. Bitmap indexes **do** store null entries.

So, if you have:

> select * from mytable
>   where mycolumn is null

and you have a standard B-tree index on `mycolumn`, then the query **can't** use the index as the "null" isn't in the index.

(If the index is against multiple columns, and one of the indexed columns is not null then there will be an entry in the index.)

Comment: The question concerned a `is not null` lookup, not `is null`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on that column.

To make sure the index is used, it should be on the index and other columns in the where.

ocdecio answered:

> If you are doing a select *, then it would make sense to do a table scan rather than using the index.

That's not strictly true; an index will be used if there is an index that fits your where clause, and the query optimizer decides using that index would be faster than doing a table scan. If there is no index, or no suitable index, only then must a table scan be done.

Comment: Great comments on Select * 
Just to clarify though - we never user SELECT * for other reasons - we always include our column list in SELECT clauses.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking whether Oracle's statistics on the table are up to date. It may not know that a full table scan will be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle database don't index null values at all in regular (b-tree) indexes, so it can't use it nor you can't force oracle database to use it.

BR

Comment: This question is about `is NOT null`.  All the relevant values will be in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Using hints should be done only as a work around rather than a solution.

As mentioned in other answers, the null value is not available in B-TREE indexes.

Since you know that you have mostly null values in this column, would you be able to replace the null value by a range for instance.

That really depends on your column and the nature of your data but typically, if your column is a date type for instance:

`where mydatecolumn is not null`
Can be translated in a rule saying: I want all rows which have a date.

Then you can most definitely do this:
where mydatecolumn <=sysdate (in oracle)

This will return all rows with a date and ommit null values while taking advantage of the index on that column without using any hints.

Answer (score -1):

See http://www.oracloid.com/2006/05/using-index-for-is-null/

If your index is on one single field, it will NOT be used. Try to add a dummy field or a constant in the index:

```
create index tind on t(field_to_index, 1);
```