# How can I avoid IS [NOT] NULL in an SQL select statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, null

`IS [NOT] NULL` meddles with the indexes of SQL statements in Oracle, is there any way I can replace `IS NULL` in an SQL statement?

According to Oracle 9i Performance Tuning Tips and Techniques, having IS [NOT] NULL suppresses the indexes of the columns.

For example:

```
select * from users where user_id is not null;
```

Comment: What are the reasons you are down voting this?

Comment: I didn't down vote you but the title and the question itself have grammatical errors which mean that it doesn't read very well.

Comment: Didn't vote. I'll try to show what is unclear with this question. What do you mean by "meddles with the indexes"? Try to give more details, add an example, explain the problem...

Comment: thanks, let me quickly do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no efficient way to do the same thing without changing the data.

You can use a magic value instead of null, for example -1. That would allow you to make the field non-nullable, which increases performance somewhat, and works better with indexes. However, this conflicts with the usual recommendation to avoid magic values, so it's a compromise between performance and best practice.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Oracle, but it does allow expression indexes. Can't you create an index on the boolean expression `field IS NULL`? Coming from PostgreSQL, where I'm using those expression for indexing IS NULL, and since 9.0 [leverages indexes for IS NOT NULL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.0#IS_NOT_NULL_can_now_use_indexes) by default, it seems weird to me that "the all mighty" Oracle won't allow to use indexes for IS NULL.

Answer (score 2):

Are you allowed to change the db structure?

If yes, in order to not have any `WHERE column IS NULL` or `WHERE column IS NOT NULL` condition in your queries, then fully normalize your tables (i.e. [5NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_normal_form) or [6NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_normal_form)) and make all columns that are used in conditions `NOT NULL`.

---

I'm not an Oracle expert but I seriously doubt that a serious RDBMS such as Oracle cannot use index on a nullable column. See this question and answers that support this opinion. Perhaps the problems (you think) you have are not caused by the `NULL`s in your column but by the selectivity of them: [oracle-10g-optimize-where-is-not-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721556/oracle-10g-optimize-where-is-not-null)

---

For your simple query:

```
select * from users where user_id is not null;
```

the optimizer will choose not to use the index - as it would do for any other query - if the selectivity is not high enough. If the Nulls are few on the table, then fully scanning the table will be faster - or at least the optimizer thinks so.

Comment: I very much like the idea of making the column(s) `NOT NULL` in SQL DDL but why do you equate this with normalization? If you are asserting that the null value has no place in the relational model and therefore violates 1NF then I would again agree. BUt I rather suspect you had something else in mind as regards your "normalize your tables" advice but what is it please?

Comment: "I seriously doubt that a serious RDBMS such as Oracle cannot use index on a nullable column" -- see @a_hore_with_no_name's answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen: *"the null value has no place in the relational model"*, That's exactly what I meant. In theory that's all well. In practise though, I think it's rare to find a database without any NULLable column.

Comment: Yes, I read a_horse_with_no_name's answer. I had no idea about such details and the differences between `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` in Oracle.

Comment: Ah, then you meant *fully* normalize. A table in 1NF is normalized. A table is fully normalized only if it is in 5NF or 6NF. A table in 6NF will have no nullable columns.

Comment: Yes, "fully normalize", "further normalize" explains my thoughts better, thnx for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

For `IS NOT NULL` your claim is not true. Oracle *will* use an index on that column (provided an index scan is indeed faster than a full table scan - which is not always the case)

Oracle does not put *tuples* that are all NULL into an index, therefor if you define an index on a single column e.g. `CREATE INDEX idx_user_id ON person (user_id)` that index will not contain rows where user_id is NULL. As a result of that, the index cannot be used for a `IS NULL` condition.

However you can use a workaround if you need to do frequent `IS NULL` selections, by forcing the nulls to be indexed using a constant in the index definition: `CREATE INDEX idx_user_id ON person (user_id, 1)`. That index will be used for a IS NULL condition (again provided other access methods are not more efficient).